# SQL advance filtiring

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to filter data using where clause but I need to filter two types of rows.
for example:

```
processID ProcessName processorName
-----------------------------------
461        a                ABC
116        a                XYZ
755        c                ABC
031        b                EFG
333        b                KLM
```

suppose we have this table with three coloumns , I want to retrieve rows with `ProcessName` with `a` and `b`, but not only this `a` with the `processorName` of `ABC` and `b` with the `processorName` of `KLM`.

Comment: `WHERE (ProcessName LIKE 'a' AND processorName LIKE 'ABC') OR (ProcessName LIKE 'b' AND processorName LIKE 'KLM')`

Comment: Please define more your question in order to we help you.

Answer (score 3):

this should do it:

```
SELECT processID, ProcessName, processorName
FROM table
WHERE (ProcessName = 'a' AND processorName = 'ABC')
   OR (ProcessName = 'b' AND processorName = 'KLM')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
select * from table a where processNmae='a' and processorname ='ABC'

    union

    select * from table a where processNmae='b' and processorname='KLM'
```

### <kbd>[see fiddle demo here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3fa91/3)</kbd>

Comment: I am using Sql views can i still use "union"?

Comment: This is not correct to do, because simple where will have 1 select and this will have multiple selects followed by a union\

Comment: @Naresh u mean a `Select 'a' union select 'b'` doesn't work ?

Comment: It will work, but doesnt serve the purpose. Union in this case makes 2 selects followed by an append, where as the where clause is simple filtering.

Comment: Thanks for d I/p will try it again !!

Comment: Why the use of `like` in the query? `=` should be sufficient.

Comment: @PeterSchuetze : ya,that should be enough i added `like` just in case if theres 'ABC1' or'KLM1'

Comment: @Naresh : you could see the demo i put !!